Process.processName method keep calling wrong name
I used C# to write UDP Server code and this is for the close application code. Everything works well except this part. I would like to close calculator so that I specified processName as "calc" but in "if" part it keep calling wrong process. How to figure out this?
       private void CloseApplications(string[] processNames)
       {
           foreach (string processName in processNames)
           {


               foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if (process.ProcessName.StartsWith(processName))
                       {

                           if (!process.HasExited)
                           {
                               process.Kill();
                               UpdateLabel2("Exit");
                           }
                       }
                   }

                   catch (Win32Exception ex)
                   {
                       UpdateLabel2($"Win32Exception: {ex.Message}");
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       UpdateLabel2("종료 실패: {ex.Message}");
                   }
               }
           }
       }

I tried all the way that GPT asked to do but still cant figure it out. This is remote UDP server

I think you might have the process name wrong.  Certainly on my system I have "CalculatorApp".

$ symbol missing in the second catch. can you share the UpdateLabel2 code as well.

Starting with Win10, calc.exe actually starts a UWP app.  Named CalculatorApp.exe

Also, StartsWith does a case-sensitive comparison. So "calc" will never match "CalculatorApp". See this overload to do a case-insensitive comparison.

As for how to figure this out? Set a breakpoint at the if statement there and inspect the value of process.ProcessName. That'll show you what's being compared. Or, you could write a simple program to output all the process names so you can examine them. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Thanks for your helps problem solved!
